# VBA Find Blank Cells and insert text

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in column A on my workbook, they are grouped with spaces in between them. I need VBA to find first empty cell and add text "Progress" then find the next empty cell and add text "Plan"

The codes below are only adding the same text to each blank, how can I tell it once first blank if filled, move to next blank and add XXX text?

```
 Sub getnext()

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
      Cells(i, 1).Value = "Progress"
      Cells(i, 1).Value = "Plan"
    End If
Next i

End Sub



 Sub FirstEmpty()
lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MR = Range("A1:A" & lRow)
For Each cell In MR
If cell.Text = "" Then cell.Value = "Progress"

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include an incrementing variable to keep track of how many substitutions you've made. See below for an example:

```
Sub FindBlankAndFill()
    Dim cnter As Integer

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    cnter = 0

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            Select Case cnter
                Case 0: Cells(i, 1).Value = "Progress"
                Case 1: Cells(i, 1).Value = "Plan"
                Case Else: Cells(i, 1).Value = "Not Yet Defined"
            End Select
            cnter = cnter + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I knew there was something I was missing! Thanks for the help @user3561813

Answer (score 3):

With data like:

[image]

This small macro will place something in the first empty cell and something different in the next empty cell:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A")).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r(1) = "Initial"
    r(2) = "next"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Worked Perfect! Thanks so much! @Gary's Student